# TikaOnDotNet - Cannot extract text file content

Tags: c#, .net, apache-tika

I have a text file with Cyrillic letters and ANSI encryption.
When I try to extract the file content with TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction I get only empty rolls. If I check to see the Content-type of the file it returns - application/octet-stream.
When I change the encoding to UTF-8 the content is extracted properly.

Comment: What encoding is your original source text file?  Is it 8-BIT ASCII, or UTF-8?  Does it have a BOM ?

Comment: It is 8-bit ASCII (Windows-1251).

Comment: 8-bit ASCII doesn't support Cyrillic letters unless you change the code page.  TBH the days of ASCII were numbered a long time ago.  We've had UTF-8, UTF-16 & Unicode for many years, which are designed to prevent this problem.  Why not convert your 'text' file to a modern format?

Comment: We were hoping to prevent that. But looks like we have no choice. Thanks for the help.